# How to make fast read/write access for rclone synced directory?

Tags: mount, filesystem, cloud, rclone

I want to sync my Google Drive directory with local directory and after some research I concluded that `rclone` seems to fit my needs, but I still can't figure out some nuances.

As for now, I managed to create connection and mount directory by the following command:

```bsh
rclone mount --daemon --vfs-cache-mode writes my_gdrive: /home/user/my_gdrive
```

**Question:** It works, but I found out it is really slow. I need to switch quickly between rather small text/image files (~1-1000 Kb each and whole drive won't grow bigger ~1-5 Gb). **How can I make it faster?**

My first assumption was to try [--vfs-cache-mode full](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/#vfs-cache-mode-full), but I don't really understand what values to use for `--buffer-size` and `--vfs-read-ahead` flags and is it right thing to do even?

**Note:** my `/home/user/my_gdrive` is on SSD drive

Answer (score 0):

I use a command like this

```
rclone sync --drive-chunk-size 512M  --transfers=45 --checkers=45 --progress /localdir534 /remotedir534
```

Answer (score 0):

First unmount it, then use this instead:

```
rclone mount --daemon --vfs-cache-mode full my_gdrive: /home/user/my_gdrive --buffer-size 64M --transfers 16 --no-modtime --no-checksum --vfs-read-ahead 16M --vfs-fast-fingerprint
```

By the way, for small files, Dropbox works much better than Google Drive. Just replace "my_gdrive:" with your Dropbox remote.